# get all notifications from the iOS notification center with RNFirebase

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I'm building a React Native app using RNFirebase 5.20.1 and looking for a method to get all notifications in the notification center (for iOS), similar to `getDeliveredNotifications` 
(https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.55/pushnotificationios#getdeliverednotifications).

I'm not finding anything like this method in RNFirebase's source code or docs though 
(https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/v5.x.x/ios/RNFirebase/notifications/RNFirebaseNotifications.m).

RNFirebase does provide a method `removeAllDeliveredNotifications` which clears all notifications from the notification center, but returns a promise containing void, so I can't get any data from that either.

I've thought about also implementing the RN PushNotificationIOS library, but a little bit wary it would conflict with RNFirebase (there's overlap with RNFirebase integration methods, and my native code understanding is pretty rudimentary).

Any ideas? Maybe I'm simply not seeing a RNFirebase method to do this...

UPDATE

So I've integrated the PushNotificationIOS library and just changed one thing in the AppDelegate.m file, and it appears to have worked - I'm able to access notifications from the notification center.

`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
  [[RNFirebaseMessaging instance] didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}`